# Read all files inside a folder including files in subfolders using C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to read all files inside a given folder(path to folder) using FindFirstFile method provide in windows API. Currently I'm only succeeded in reading files inside the given folder. I could not read files inside sub folders. Can anyone help me to do this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `FindFirstFile`/`FindNextFile`, some of the "files" it returns will actually be directories.
You can check if something is a directory or not by looking at the `dwFileAttributes` field of the `WIN32_FIND_DATA` structure that gets returned to you.

If you find one that is a directory, then you can simply call your file finding function recursively to go into the subfolders.

Note: Make sure to put in a special case for the `.` and `..` psuedo-directories, otherwise your function will recurse into itself and you'll get a stack overflow

Here's the documentation if you haven't already found it:

[FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418(VS.85).aspx)

[WIN32_FIND_DATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365740(v=VS.85).aspx)

[possible values for dwFileAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332330(v=VS.85).aspx) (remember these are all bit flags, so you'll have to use & to check)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) which will not only give you a clean API, but will also make your code portable on all supported platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scx99850%28VS.80%29.aspx) from MSDN using `CFileFind`.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this code to read the files in the specified directory.

```
CFileFind finder;

BOOL bWorking = finder.FindFile( directory );

while( bWorking )
{
    bWorking = finder.FindNextFile();                   
}//end while
```